# Make table row with Odd and Even if have a accordion-form

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem, i make a table with accordion form with this codes

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredTrips">
  <tr class="accordion" data-bind="click: $parent.toggleDetail">
                                        <td style="text-align:center"><h4><strong><span data-bind="text: jamFormated"></strong></h4></td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center"><h4><strong><span data-bind="text: arrivalFormated"></strong></h4></td>
                                        <td><h4><strong><span data-bind="text: armada"></strong></h4></td>
                                        <td><div style='width:100px;padding-right:30px;'><span style='font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;float:right;' data-bind="text: hargaFormated"></span></div></td>
                                        <td><h4><strong><span data-bind="text: vendor"></strong></h4></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div>
                                                <a class="mau-pilih-travel pull-right"><span><strong><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Pilih Travel</strong></span></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-bind="visible: showDetail">
      <td colspan="6">
      <!-- some of content -->
      </td>

   </tr>
```

OUTPUT can be found at this URL : http://stage.travelcar.co.id/travel-malang-juanda

i wanna to make Even and Odd condition just for `<tr>` with `class="accordion"`, but even and odd impact all `<tr>` in that table.

this is my jquery codes that will be add CSS class odd and even as to change the background color

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("table.list tbody tr.accordion:odd").addClass("odd");
        $("table.list tbody tr.accordion:even").addClass("even");
    });
</script>
```

how to make odd and even condition just for tr with class correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector and the `addClass()` is correct. I question if it's getting applied *after* you load the table to the DOM (I see from the page source that the `table` is not a part of the original page source).

You might also try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("table.list>tbody>tr.accordion").filter(':even').addClass('even').end().filter(':odd').addClass('odd')
    });
</script>
```

This says

`$("table.list>tbody>tr.accordion")`: get me the `table` classed as list, get its `tbody`, get its `tr` classed as accordion.

`.filter(':even').addClass('even')`: out of all those `tr`, limit the selection to the ones that are :even, then class them as even.

`.end()`: go back to the previous selection (before filtering to :even)

`.filter(':odd').addClass('odd')`: out of all those `tr`, limit the selection to the ones that are :odd, then class them as odd.